# Stupeflix API fontname error

Tags: php, wordpress

We have a website that has a webform.  In the form the user can select a few photos from there computer, facebook, or from our provided gallery.  Our site is built in Wordpress, latest version.  Today, I noticed that most of the videos are not being created by the Stupeflix API.

We seem to be getting a strange response from Stupeflix when i look at the Activity Log.

Here is the error:

{"error": "InvalidFontError: Invalid font, file name = http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/_assets/klavika.otf, XML line 19."}

It seems to be having trouble with the Klavika font only I'm not sure if that is really the case.  The XML it is referring too is the definition.xml.php file that we use to generate the info that Stupeflix needs to generate the video.

Here's why, I tried switching the fontname to "verdana" which is a font that is safe to use in Stupeflix and then i receive a totally weird error in the response activity log.

So, what else is odd about this is that last year we had the same font.

After i made that font change to verdana and tested, I received a different error.  So now its saying:

{"error": "File does not exists:/data/eph1/dragon/tmp/dragon-video.create-XDASTJIZVRPRG55QEWQVLPLWBE-G7Mmq4/audios/file_0.mp3"}

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?  Everything seemed to be working fine yesterday and for weeks/months prior, but then today, it is not working anymore.

Is this an issue on Stupeflix's side?

Comment: must be a stupeflix error. I began receiving the same error. I contacted stupeflix support. I'll post the response once received.

Comment: I did as well, if I hear from them, I'll let everyone know what they say.

Comment: nothing from support, but the Stupeflix API seems to be up and working now.

Comment: I just now got a reply and they have there engineering team looking into the issue, I am going to refer them to this thread since now i know its not just me.  Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting today, I am getting the same error:

> InvalidFontError: Invalid font, file name = ...

My guess is that Stupeflix did some sort of update today as the service was down for a while. Not sure if they changed or broke something to do with fonts.

Comment: it did turn out to be an issue on there end, this has been fixed for awhile.  Thanks.